# React: how to keep sidepanel state between url changes with history.push()?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, browser-history

I have a fixed sidepanel that contains a search bar with filter buttons similar to https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

The list items are clickable and trigger `history.push()` for nested path urls.

The nested path structure is

```
/category-1
/category-1/product-1
/category-1/product-2
/category-2
/category-2/product-1
/category-2/product-2
 .
 .
 .
/category-n/product-m
/category-n/product-k
```

User can scroll the sidepanel's list and select filters. However, a click on a list item (with `onClick()` followed by `history.push()`) causes the whole page (including the sidepanel) to render. This in turn doesn't keep the sidepanel's state so the filters and the scroll position are reset.

The parent `render: function()` looks like:

```
return(
  <div id="main-view">
    <Sidepanel history={this.props.history} properties={this.props.properties} />
    React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {this.props});
  </div>
);
```

The `React.cloneElement()` is the product info container that should render only.

I'm using `react-router, react-redux and redux-simple-router`.

Do I need to store the sidepanel's list scroll position and filter values outside of the sidepanel? Or is there a better way to keep the sidepanel's state between the url changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your architecture is not aligned with what you want to do.

Simply render the navigation in your top-level, parent component and it will never lose state - for example in your `Application` component. Then `SidePanel` wouldn't be affected by route change.

Also you could pass down a callback to set / alter navigation from children, if needed (for example `hide()` or `addMenuItems()`).

Comment: Thanks @leo – this solved the issue. I moved the Sidepanel to the top level in `Application` and now its state stays while the url gets update. Perfect!

Comment: nice, glad to help!